# Grant locked external HDD access for another PC

Tags: windows-10, permissions, external-hard-drive

I was trying to mess around with permissions for my external HDD. I've managed to lock it for everyone aside for my own pc with the following settings:

[External HDD security settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkaJ2.png)

As you can see, the first permission is my E-Mail or user permission which grants full control, and the second one is for administrators of my pc.

*but this is where things get fuzzy*

When I try to plug the same external HDD in to my laptop. I get the access denied message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgYqC.png)

Even though I'm logged in to my laptop with the same E-Mail as well? What I can make of this is that the permission is just pc/ machine bound but then what would my settings need to be in order to be able to use my external HDD on my laptop as well?

Looking forward to hear your responses!

CCG

Comment: You do know that setting the permissions on an external HDD is sort of pointless.  An Administrator on any machine it’s connected to can simply take ownership of the contents.  If you really want to proceed, as an Administrator on the other pc, add a user to the ACL.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know that that was the case... Nor do I know what ACL exactly is, googling it showed me something about Access Control List but how can I exactly use that to my advantage? Thank you for your time!

Comment: As an Administrator you can modify the permissions of any file or folder and add yourself or any user to the access control list. Which is the reason it’s a worthless endeavor to set the permissions on a external drive.

Comment: I see.. It was worth trying anyway! Thank you again!